# Server Migration Issues

Tags: migration

I am attempting to rebuild a site that I created for a client using wordpress.com and hosted through WordPress. Probably not surprisingly, the site was pretty slow on the WP servers. Beyond this, it needed to be redesigned and when we integrated an e-com plugin the store page became really slow. (load times in excess of 14 sec for interactivity)

I wanted to start from scratch and rebuild the site so I purchased hosting with siteground, added the URL as an externally registered domain in my siteground, account and created an installation of WordPress. I pointed the DNS at siteground servers and it populated just fine in about 12 hours. The only problem is that now wordpress isn't accepting my login credentials to get into the wp admin. Is this something that will resolve itself in a few hours/days? Or, option "oh crap" did I miss a step? Keep in mind, I intentionally did not actually migrate the old site as I intended to start from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possibilities:

1 - your site hasn't fully propagated yet

When you said you "created an installation of WordPress" it sounds like you have a completely new install with new username and password. If you are using that new login and you can't get it, DNS probably has not completely propagated. It can take a couple of days. You will know this is the case if you use your old login credentials and get in - that means DNS hasn't fully switched over yet.

2 - you're using the wrong login credentials

You can double-check your login credentials using phpMyAdmin. Go to the `wp_users` table to find your username. You can either reset the password from the login page, or directly here, by typing in a password and then making sure to use MD5 for that data so it encrypts it for you. Then once again you will go to the login screen and if it doesn't work, you'll know it's DNS.

3 - wp-config settings are wrong

Last case, if your wp-config file is pointing to the wrong database - such as the old one - that will prevent you from getting in as well. Double-check that the file points to the correct db.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It looks like its just a propagation problem after all. I checked the config settings and they list the new database. I was using the wrong password at first but even the correct login credentials didn't work. I'll give it a few more hours.

Answer (score 0):

Above all, I supposed the password was changed during the migration.

Siteground support ssh access, and you can use wp-cli as well. Through Wp-CLI, you can add new administrator account, or you can reset the password. You will be able to check your old account through new account because they are the same admin level account.